# Georeferencer - GDAL is missing on the QGIS 3

Tags: georeferencing, qgis-3, missing-data

OS - ArchLinux 64bits

SPECS - i3-3220 - 6gb ram

QGIS 3.0.3 installed as follow.

$ sudo pacman -S qgis gdal python-gdal python-psycopg2 python-owslib python-yaml python-pygments

$ yaourt -S python-jinja-time

On the section ALL - do not appear.
[image]

On the INSTALLED - do not appear.
[image]

As you can see, georeferencer is missing.

Comment: GDAL Georeferencer has been moved in QGIS 3.26 to the Layer menu: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/434544/finding-georeferencer-in-qgis

Answer (score 4):

You need to install some optional dependencies of QGIS: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/qgis/

sudo pacman -S --needed fcgi gpsbabel gsl python-jinja python-numpy cmake python-six qt5-tools txt2tags