# Finding Georeferencer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing

I'm using QGIS 3.26 and I can't find the Georeferencer.

I've basically looked everywhere. It should be in the raster section, but it isn't there. I checked all of my plugins if there was anything, but there wasn't anything, and I even searched it up and I didn't find anything either.

[image]

Answer (score 38):

Since version 3.26 it has moved to the Layer menu because it now supports both raster and vector data. This is now [documented](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/georeferencer.html#usual-procedure), though it [wasn't](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/49139) when the question was asked.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In QGIS before 3.26 it's not a PlugIn, it's in the Raster Tab.
[image]