# No Raster Georeferencer in PLugin List QGIS 3.26.1-Buenos Aires

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, georeferencing

I have QGIS 3.26.1-Buenos Aires
The Raster Georeferncer is not located under "Raster"
Nor does it appear when I search for "Georeferencer" in the "Manage and Install Plugins" search.
Nor is it listed under my installed plugins.

What can I do?

Comment: I am on a Mac 11.6.8 Big Sur

Comment: Found the answer here! https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/434544/finding-georeferencer-in-qgis