# Missing Georeferencer in latest QGIS 3.28

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I've just updated my QGIS to the latest version 3.28. Then I realised that my georeferencer tool dissappeared from the Raster tab.

[image]

Then I go to my plugin dialog, I couldn't find georeferencer in either installed or not installed.
[image]

Anyone has an idea what's going on here?

Comment: It's now under the Layer Menu. [Link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/434544/finding-georeferencer-in-qgis)

Answer (score 22):

Because it can be used on vector layers as well, it is now found under the Layer menu (explained [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/georeferencer.html#usual-procedure)):

[image]

Doc:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/georeferencer.html

Comment: I found it there, thanks heaps!