# Georeferencing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

ask about QGIS and georeferencing, in version 3.28 I can't find it in plugins, neither to activate it nor to install it, can someone guide me how I can make a georeferencing in this version of QGIS,

Comment: Menus : Raster>Georeference

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/map_georeferencing.html?highlight=georeference

Comment: Hello, when I enter the raster menu, the georeference option is not there and when I go to accessories I cannot find it

Comment: Look in the Layer Menu for georeferencer.

Comment: Duplicate of [Finding Georeferencer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/434544/finding-georeferencer-in-qgis)